# can not generate flutter apk file

Tags: flutter, apk, generate

I'm trying to generate flutter apk file using the following command

flutter build apk --target-platform=android-arm

but I've got the following error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not download flutter_embedding_release.jar (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c)
  >   Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_release/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutt
  >   er_embedding_release-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar'.
  >   Read timed out
  >   Could not download armeabi_v7a_release.jar (io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_release:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c)
  >   Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_release/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/armeabi_v7a
  >   _release-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar'.
  >   Read timed out
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insigh
  ts.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      64.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

how to solve this problem ??

Comment: did you tried using flutter clean and then build apk using flutter build apk command

Comment: I’ve fixed the problem, I just upgraded the flutter sdk and run flutter clean and then everything works fine